# relative urls in <link>-Tags not converted when updating to TYPO3 8/9

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

Normally the old link syntax is converted in the new syntax while updating TYPO3. But there is one exception. When the link contains a relative url the syntax is not converted:

```
<link job/karriere/artikel/titel-des-artikels/>linktext</link>
```

Will remain in the old syntax in the database. In TYPO3 8 the link is shown in the frontend but vanishes from the rte. If you save the entry in TYPO3 the link is gone. In TYPO3 9 the link vanishes from the frontend too.

There is a bug entry in the forge:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/80903

but it seems that there is no plan to fix this problem in the near future. My problem is, that I have to upgrade installation with thousands of such links - no chance to fix the problem manually.

Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you entered the relative link as external URL. But it should be a link to a (news)record.

As you passed TYPO3's URL generation you should be consequent and replace the links with a naked a-tag.

Maybe with a regexp-replacement. something like:

```
\<link (.*)\>(.*)\</link\>  => <a href="$1">$2</a>
```